# Transcendental elements in $k[[x]]$ over the field $k(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have a hard time to prove that $k[[x]]$ contains an element which is transcendental over $k(x)$. Could you please explain the some idea how to do that?

Comment: FWIW, when $k$ is countable a simple cardinality argument works.

Comment: Try showing that $\sum_{n \ge 0} x^{n^2}$ is an example. In characteristic zero, try showing that $\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ is an example.